# Webpack and SASS hot reloading

Tags: sass, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader

I'm making a simple html and CSS app. I need to my SASS changes to show up on the website LIVE as im developing.

And once all the SASS and development is complete I will run `webpack -b` and webpack should convert the SASS to CSS.

I'm sure someone has done this before. Thanks.

Comment: What does your current webpack configuration look like?

Comment: @katranci This is the github repo im trying to use https://github.com/bensmithett/webpack-css-example

Comment: @katranci ?? any good news

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem stems from wrong `output.publicPath` config in webpack.config.js file. In order for live-reload to work, requests going to webpack bundles (e.g. app.css, app.js) should be handled by webpack-dev-server. For the repository you're referring to, this could be done by setting `output.publicPath` to `"/build"`.

Run `webpack-dev-server --inline` on the command line after changing config file and then go to `http://localhost:8080`. Now the page should reload everytime you change and save a file.